Injectivity of Hom Map between Elliptic curves and Tate modules
I am reading Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, JH Silverman, and I am struck on Exercise 3.14.
The question is to prove directly (without using a stronger result proved earlier) that the map $ \text{Hom}(E_1, E_2) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(T_l(E_1), T_l(E_2))$ is injective where $E_i$ are elliptic curves and $T_l(E_i)$ are the corresponding $l$-adic Tate modules.
The problem also has a hint which says that if $\phi : E_1 \rightarrow E_2$ maps to $0 \in \text{Hom}(T_l(E_1), T_l(E_2))$, then $E_1[l^n] \subset ker(\phi)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Here's what I tried. Using the hint and the existence of dual isogeny, we have that $ker([l^n] \subset ker([m])$ for all $n$, where $m$ = deg($\phi$). So, for all integers $n$, there exists a map (isogeny) ${\lambda}_n : E_1 \rightarrow E_1$ such that ${\lambda}_n \circ [l^n] = [m]$. If we can prove that this implies $l^n$ divides $m$, then that would be true for all integral $n$ and so $m$ and subsequently $\phi$ must be the zero map . But I am not sure if this is at all true or how to prove it if it is true.

The degree of an isogeny is multiplicative, i.e., $\deg(\psi \circ \phi) = \deg(\psi)\deg(\phi)$. Do you see how this helps you prove what you want to show?

Yeah, that should work. Thank you. Looking at the degrees of the maps in the equation ${\lambda}_n \circ [l^n] = m$, we get $deg({\lambda}_n) \cdot l^{2n} = m^2 $, which then gives the divisibility condition we need.
